# D3 update data on the wrong bars

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to update data on a click but the bars that are changing are not the right ones. There is something I cant quite fix with the select. On click the grey bars, which should be bar2 are updating. It should be bar.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/kaqv37gu/

D3 chart:

```
var values = feature.properties;
var data = [
    {name:"Employment rate",value:values["ERate15P"]},
    {name:"Participation rate",value:values["PR15P"]},
    {name:"Unemployment rate",value:values["URate15P"]}
];

var margin = {top: 70, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 50},
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    barHeight = height / data.length;

// Scale for X axis
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 100]) //set input to a scale of 0 - 1. The index has a score scale of 0 to 1. makes the bars more accurate for comparison.
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Employment rate", "Participation rate", "Unemployment rate"])
    .rangeRoundBands([0, height], 0.2);

var svg = d3.select(div).select("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .classed("chartInd", true);

var bar2 = svg.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

var bar = svg.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });


bar2.append("rect")
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand()-15)
    .attr("fill", "#EDEDED")
    .attr("width", 300);


bar.append("rect")
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand()-15)
    .attr("fill", "#B44978")
    .attr("width", function(d){return x(d.value);});

bar.append("text")
    .attr("class", "text")
    .attr("x", 298)
    .attr("y", y.rangeBand() - 50)
    .text(function(d) { return d.value + " %"; })
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end");

bar.append("text")
    .attr("class", "text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name) -5 ; })
    .attr("y", y.rangeBand()-50)
    //.attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

d3.select("p")
            .on("click", function() {
                //New values for dataset
                var values = feature.properties;
            var dataset = [
                            {name:"Employment rate",value:values["ERate15_24"]},
                            {name:"Participation rate",value:values["PR15_24"]},
                            {name:"Unemployment rate",value:values["URate15_24"]}
                          ];
                //Update all rects
                var bar = svg.selectAll("rect")
                   .data(dataset)
                   .attr("x", function(d){return x(d.value);})
                   .attr("width", function(d){return x(d.value);})
                   });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var bar2 = svg.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

var bar = svg.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });
```

'bar2' above generates 3 new g elements (one for each datum)

Since you don't set attr("class","bar") for these then 'bar' will also generate 3 new g elements - (if you had set the class attribute bar would return empty as no new elements would be generated and you'd see missing stuff)

Further on you add rects to all these g elements for six rectangles in total and in the click function you select all these rectangles and re-attach 3 fresh bits of data

Since bar2 was added first the rectangles in its g elements are hoovering up the new data

You need to select and set different classes on the g elements, .selectAll("g.bar") and .attr("class", "bar") for bar, and .selectAll("g.bar2") and .attr("class", "bar2") for bar2 (use the same name to keep it simple)

then in the new data you need select only the rects belonging to g elements of the bar class: svg.selectAll(".bar rect")

Another way would be to have only one set of g elements and add two types of rectangle (differentiated by class attribute)

Comment: mgraham, this works! Thank you for the explanation, it helped me to understand further how to manipulate elements in a D3 svg graphic!